# Google ecommerce tracking code for Dukapress wordpress E-commerce plugin

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

How I can get e-commerce tracking by google analytics from Dukapress Wordpress ecommerce plugin? I have already switched on e-commerce tracking from google analytics.But can't find options to configure it from my site. I am using Dukapress e-commerce plugin.

And One more thing I need to know, I have find an article here http://www.sitepoint.com/track-ecommerce-transactions-google-analytics-reports/ 
But I want to know that I need to write "_add_item" code once or more? If more, then how much?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should post only one question per question (it sounds to me like you're asking two.)  Making one post per specific thing you need to know will help you get answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `_addItem` for each line of item bought in the e-commerce tracking code. Once all items are added into the transaction queue, you should do a `_trackTrans`.

Just like the post you are referring to, it says:

> "3. Add individual products
>   A code block is required for **all products purchased within the transaction**. The data is required in the following order:"

So one `_addItem` per product bought within a transaction.